# Laravel FormRequest failed validation returns 302 redirect instead of 422 with errors

Tags: laravel, validation

I have modalform on website. Full backend and frontend code is below. I cannot understand how validation works. When I put more than 20 symbols in name field I don't see any errors in Laravel debugbar, no info in Session tab in Laravel Debugbar.
I just can see in Chrome Devtools under network tab some info about it:

- On the screenshot below you can see that first modalform request has status 200. This happens when I put name between 3 and 20 symbols. And finally I receive email in my mailbox.
- And second modalform request has status 302. But I don't see any error on webpage, no errors in Laravel debugbar, no info in Session tab in Laravel Debugbar.

[image: Chrome devtools + laravel debugbar]

Can somebody explain me how it works and what is wrong with my code? Without seeing validation errors it is very hard to find the problem.

I have modalform on website.
**routes\web.php**

```
Route::post('/modalform',    'MainController@modalform')->name('modalform');
```

**app\Http\Controllers\MainController.php**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\Modalform;
use App\Http\Requests\ModalformRequest;


class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function modalform(ModalformRequest $request) {
        
        Mail::to( config('mail.to.address') )->send(new Modalform());

        return response()->json([
            'status'        => 'success',
            'messageHeader'     => 'Your message sent!', 
            'messageContent'    => 'We will contact you soon.'
            ]);
}
```

**app\Http\Requests\ModalformRequest.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ModalformRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'      => 'string|between:3,20|required',
        ];
    }
}
```

**app\Mail\Modalform.php**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\ModalformRequest;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class Modalform extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $subject = 'request from Modalform';

    public function build(ModalformRequest $request)
    {
        $this->from( config('mail.from.address') )
             ->view('emails.modalform')
             ->withRequest($request);
    }
}
```

**views\emails\modalform.blade.php**

```
<p><strong>{{ $request->name }}</strong></p>
<p><strong>{{ $request->phone }}</strong></p>
<p><strong>{{ $request->email }}</strong></p>
<p><strong>{{ $request->address }}</strong></p>
<p>{{ $request->message }}</p>
<p> Message sent from <a href="{{ $request->headers->get('referer') }}">{{ $request->headers->get('referer') }}</a></p>
```

**views\partials\modalform.blade.php**

```
<style>
        [x-cloak] {
            display: none;
        }
</style>

<div class="topbar bg-white border-b border-gray-100"
     x-data="topbar()"
     x-cloak
    >

    <div class="flex justify-between items-center flex-wrap text-xs p-0 max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        
        <div class="cursor-pointer">
            <div class="relative" @click="openModal = !openModal">
                <svg class="h-6 w-6 fill-current">
                    <use xlink:href="envelope-outline"></use>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Modal -->
<div x-show="openModal" class="fixed z-50 inset-0 overflow-y-auto" 
        x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-300"
        x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 transform scale-50"
        x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 transform scale-100"
        x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-150"
        x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 transform scale-100"
        x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 transform scale-50"
        x-cloak
        >

  <div class="flex items-center justify-center min-h-screen pt-4 px-4 pb-20 text-center sm:block sm:p-0">
    <!--
      Background overlay, show/hide based on modal state.
    -->
    <div class="fixed inset-0 transition-opacity" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-gray-500 opacity-75"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- This element is to trick the browser into centering the modal contents. -->
    <span class="hidden sm:inline-block sm:align-middle sm:h-screen" aria-hidden="true">&#8203;</span>

    <!--
      Modal panel, show/hide based on modal state.
    -->
    <div @click.away="openModal = false" class="inline-block align-bottom bg-white rounded-lg text-left overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:my-8 sm:align-middle sm:max-w-lg sm:w-full" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal-headline">

      <form method="POST" action="/modalform" method="POST" @submit.prevent="submitData()">
        @csrf

      <div class="bg-white">
        <div class="modalbuttons flex place-items-center text-center border-b cursor-pointer text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900">
            <h3 class="p-2 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-blue-500"    
                @click="callback = true, zamer = false, eskiz = false"
                :class="callback ? 'bg-gray-100 text-blue-500' : ''"
                >
                Callback request
            </h3>
            <h3 class="p-2 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-blue-500"
                @click="callback = false, zamer = true, eskiz = false"
                :class="zamer ? 'bg-gray-100 text-blue-500' : ''"
                >
                Signup for a measurement
            </h3>
            <h3 class="p-2 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-blue-500" 
                @click="callback = false, zamer = false, eskiz = true"
                :class="eskiz ? 'bg-gray-100 text-blue-500' : ''"
                >
                Send sketch for quuotation
            </h3>
            <div class="p-2 place-self-stretch hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-blue-500" @click="openModal = false" >
                <span class="text-3xl">&times;</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="flex items-start flex-wrap p-5" 
            x-show="!sent"
            >

          <div class="text-left w-full">

            <div class="mt-2 grid grid-cols-2 gap-x-4 gap-y-2">
                <!-- Name -->
                <div class="name">
                    <label class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700" for="name"> Name </label>
                    <div class="relative text-gray-400 focus-within:text-gray-800">
                        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" x-model="formData.name" placeholder="Fill in the name" autofocus="autofocus" data-cip-id="name">                    
                     </div>
                </div>
               
                <!-- Phone -->
                <div class="phone">
                    <label class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700" for="phone"> Phone </label>
                    <div class="relative text-gray-400 focus-within:text-gray-800">
                        <input id="phone" type="text" name="phone" x-model="formData.phone" placeholder="Fill in the phone" autofocus="autofocus" data-cip-id="phone">                    
                     </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Email Address -->
                <div class="email" x-show="zamer || eskiz" >
                    <label class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700" for="email"> Email </label>
                    <div class="relative text-gray-400 focus-within:text-gray-800">
                        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" x-model="formData.email" placeholder="Fill in the email" autofocus="autofocus" data-cip-id="email">                    
                     </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Address -->
                <div class="address" x-show="zamer || eskiz">
                    <label class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700" for="address"> Address </label>
                    <div class="relative text-gray-400 focus-within:text-gray-800">
                        <input id="address" type="text" name="address" x-model="formData.address" placeholder="Fill in the address" autofocus="autofocus" data-cip-id="address">                    
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Message -->
            <div class="message">
                <label class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700" for="message"> Message </label>
                <div class="relative text-gray-400 focus-within:text-gray-800">
                    <input id="message" type="text" name="message" x-model="formData.message" placeholder="Fill in the message" autofocus="autofocus" data-cip-id="message">                    
                 </div>
            </div>
            
          <p x-text="message" class="text-green-600"></p>

          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-3 sm:px-6 flex justify-between ">
            <button type="submit" @click.prevent="openModal = false"><span>Cancel</span></button>          
            <button type="submit" x-text="buttonLabel" @click.prevent="submitData()">Send</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>


    <!-- /Modal -->


</div>



    <script>

        function topbar() {
            return {
                mailTooltip: false,
                instagramTooltip: false,
                openModal: false,
                callback: true,
                zamer: false,
                eskiz: false,

                formData: {
                  name: '',
                  phone: '',
                  email: '',
                  address: '',
                  message: '',
                  _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                },

                message: '',
                loading: false,
                sent: false,
                buttonLabel: 'Send',

                resetFields() {
                        this.formData.name = '',
                        this.formData.phone = '',
                        this.formData.email = '',
                        this.formData.address = '',
                        this.formData.message = ''
                },
                
                submitData() {
                    this.buttonLabel = 'Sending...';
                    this.loading = true;
                    this.message = '';

                    fetch('/modalform', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                        body: JSON.stringify(this.formData)
                    })
                    .then(() => {
                        this.resetFields(),
                        this.message = 'Message sent successfully!',
                        this.sent = true
                    })
                    .catch(() => {
                        this.message = 'Ooops! Something went wrong!'
                    })
                    .finally(() => {
                        this.loading = false;
                        this.openModal = false;
                        this.buttonLabel = 'Send';
                        this.message = '';
                        this.sent = false
                    })                    
                },

            }

        }
    </script>
```

then in the main teplate I have this

```
@if (session('status'))
<!-- Session message -->
<session>
    <x-modules.alert style="{{ session('status') }}">
        <x-slot name="messageHeader">{{ session('messageHeader') }}</x-slot>
        <x-slot name="messageContent">{{ session('messageContent') }}</x-slot>
    </x-modules.alert>
</session>
@endif
```

Comment: Seems I found way where I can find solution, but I am at the beginning without seeing finish line. I replace code `fetch('/modalform', { ... } )`  with                     ```axios.post('/modalform', this.formData)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        this.message = response.data.name;
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        this.errors = error.message;
                    });```

Comment: Now I see response data in console if POST request is successfull and I see error messages in console if validation fails and HTTP status is 422 in this case. But still I don't see error messages on web page and I cannot understand how to get them.

Comment: I tried to assign errors array to AlpineJs errors variable, but it doesnt work. For example this declaration doesn't work `this.errors = error.message`. When I check `errors` variable in AlpineJs Chrome Devtools it is always empty even if I see errors in console.

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely because you are making a none-JSON request i.e. using the browser or not specifying the `Accept: application/json` header if using apps like Postman. Laravel's default validator checks whether the request accepts JSON or not. If it does, then it will return a 422 with errors, otherwise, Laravel will try to redirect to a specified URL hence the 302 (redirect) response. By default, if no URL is specified, Laravel will redirect to whatever the **previous** URL was. Hence in browsers, you will most likely land on the previous page if there are any validation errors.